# Looking for a Book which can summaries last 20 years of economics

Tags: finance, quantitative, economics

What I would like to read is how the economic spectrum have changed over the period ( Central banks policy decisions , QE 1/2/3 , ECB TLTRO, BOJ unlimited stimulus ). How the central bank dealt with the low yield environment with record breaking expansionary economy. I am not looking for technological advancement in the economy ( as your mentioned Elec trading,dark pools or for that matter bitcoin). But something rather how the economic landscape has changed in last 20 years

Comment: This is very broad. Do you want to discuss the 2008 Financial Crisis? Currency revaluations? The introduction of mobile phones and "gig" work? The rise of electronic trading? Political influence or implications? My point is that there is no such book and that you'll be better served focusing on a specific issue.

Comment: What I would like to read is how the economic spectrum have changed over the period   ( Central banks policy decisions , QE 1/2/3 , ECB TLTRO, BOJ unlimited stimulus ). How the central bank dealt with the low yield environment with record breaking expansionary economy. I am not looking for technological advancement in the economy ( as your mentioned Elec trading,dark pools or for that matter bitcoin). But something rather how the economic landscape has changed in last 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Rise of Carry. It'll give a very original and in my opinion correct perspective of what's happened in market and economies in the past 20 years.

It will be nothing like an economics book and more a book grounder on the realities of market structure, central banks, and participant incentives.

[https://www.amazon.com/Rise-Carry-Consequences-Volatility-Suppression/dp/1260458407](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1260458407)